# Why incompatible types after extracting edmx from template ASP.Net MVC4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to .net, more of a Java guy, but I thought I was getting the hang of it. Only now after extracting an entity data model in a database first manner I suddenly get a couple of incompatible type errors (see below). I did nothing else.

To reproduce:

1. I created a template C# ASP.Net MVC4 internet application with account controller.
2. Ran it and created a test account.
3. Stopped debugging.
4. Then extracted the .edmx via Project > Add new item > data > ADO.Net Entity Data Model using the default connection string.
5. Then try to debug again and get the following errors:

   ```
   Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'MvcApplication1.Models.UserProfile' to 'MvcApplication1.UserProfile'    <fileLocation>  268 40  MvcApplication1
   Error   2   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MvcApplication1.Models.UserProfile>.Add(MvcApplication1.Models.UserProfile)' has some invalid arguments  <fileLocation>  273 25  MvcApplication1
   Error   3   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MvcApplication1.UserProfile' to 'MvcApplication1.Models.UserProfile'   <fileLocation>  273 45  MvcApplication1
   ```

I can supply the code, but it's the default MS template code.

I wanted to do the extraction this way, so I can expand upon the default MS model to further develop in a model first way.

- What's going wrong?
- How do I fix this?
- Or am I going about this
  completely wrong? (In which case I still want to fix it if possible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that MVC4 ships with a Code First based membership model, you will find this in the AccountModels.cs file.  You are attempting to create a second model using a .edmx file, so the compiler is complaining that you have two incompatible types of the same name.

The solution to this is that you either don't add UserProfile in your .edmx file, or you get rid of the code first model and use your .edmx model only.

Comment: Thx, this is really helping me. But now I leave the code first model intact and create a new empty .edmx, how do I add relations to the entities in the code first from entities in my .edmx model?